# "The remote host closed the connection. The error code is 0x80072746." On cancelling a big report export

Tags: ssrs-2008, reporting-services

I get the following exception when i try to cancel the download of SSRS report export.

It is generated by Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd file.
Is there anything i can do to prevent this exception? I did google  before posting here but really didn't find anything useful.

```
System.Web.HttpException: The remote host closed the connection. The error code is 0x80072746. 
at System.Web.Hosting.ISAPIWorkerRequestInProcForIIS6.FlushCore(Byte[] status, Byte[] header, Int32 keepConnected, Int32 totalBodySize, Int32 numBodyFragments, IntPtr[] bodyFragments, Int32[] bodyFragmentLengths, Int32 doneWithSession, Int32 finalStatus, Boolean& async) 
at System.Web.Hosting.ISAPIWorkerRequest.FlushCachedResponse(Boolean isFinal) 
at System.Web.Hosting.ISAPIWorkerRequest.FlushResponse(Boolean finalFlush) 
at System.Web.HttpResponse.Flush(Boolean finalFlush) 
at System.Web.HttpResponse.Flush() 
at System.Web.HttpWriter.WriteFromStream(Byte[] data, Int32 offset, Int32 size) 
at System.Web.HttpResponseStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count) 
at Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportDataOperation.StreamToResponse(Stream data, HttpResponse response) 
at Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ExportOperation.PerformOperation(NameValueCollection urlQuery, HttpResponse response) 
at Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) 
at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() 
at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

Comment: How are you canceling? Just closing the page? Is this an ASP.NET application?